# Confirm DatePicker time change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, datepicker

So I have a **DatePicker** that I can change a certain field with, but I want it to update the `HTML` only when the user confirms the change.
However, currently, when I use the `(ionChange)` event in my `ion-datetime` element, it updates the UI automatically before my confirmation alert pops up.

**How can I make it so that the value in my date picker will only change when the user presses confirm?**

```
updateStartTime(startTime) {
    let alert = this.alertControl.create({
        title: 'Change start time',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to update the start time for this event?',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('cancel');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Confirm',
            handler: () => {
                console.log(startTime);
            }
        }]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

```
<ion-item detail-push>
    <ion-label><b>Start: </b></ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm A"
                  [(ngModel)]="item.EventStart"
                  (ionChange)="updateStartTime(item.EventStart)"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do a trick by keeping the old value of the `EventStart`. I added two code samples. First one will update the HTML but it will only keep the updated value if click on confirmation, otherwise it will set `DatePicker` to old value back. Second one  will work as you expected but I don't know your value of `item.EventStart` is look like. I just guess it would something similar to this pattern `'00:00'`. Sample codes will worth you than explanation in words :).

**First one**

```
  public oldEventStart = this.item.EventStart;
  updateStartTime(startTime) {
    let alert = this.alertControl.create({
      title: 'Change start time',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to update the start time for this event?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: () => {
            this.item.EventStart = this.oldEventStart;
            console.log('cancel');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          handler: () => {
            this.item.EventStart = startTime;
            this.oldEventStart = startTime;
            console.log(startTime);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
    alert.onDidDismiss(() => { this.item.EventStart = this.oldEventStart; });
  }
```

**Second one**

```
 public oldEventStart = this.item.EventStart;
  updateStartTime(startTime) {
    this.item.EventStart = new Date('2000-01-01T'+this.oldEventStart+':00.00').toISOString();
    let alert = this.alertControl.create({
      title: 'Change start time',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to update the start time for this event?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: () => {
            this.item.EventStart = this.oldEventStart;
            console.log('cancel');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          handler: () => {
            this.item.EventStart = startTime;
            this.oldEventStart = startTime;
            console.log(startTime);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
    alert.onDidDismiss(() => { this.item.EventStart = this.oldEventStart; });
  }
```

Hope this will help to solve your problem. Cheers!.

Answer (score 0):

When I use a bootstrap dialog I would use a prevent default. Try to change the following: `updateStartTime(startTime)` to `updateStartTime(startTime,e)` and then on your first line in that function add `e.preventDefault();` See if that helps. You should then be able to do whatever you like in your cancel and confirm handlers.

Comment: Getting this error `Error in ./EventModalPage class EventModalPage - caused by: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

Comment: can you try adding e to the ion-item markup: updateStartTime(item.EventStart,e)

Answer (score 0):

Just **return false** in your updateStartTime function, so that the default datepicker handler that is bound to the change event does not get called. Like this:

```
updateStartTime(startTime) {
    let alert = this.alertControl.create({
        title: 'Change start time',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to update the start time for this event?',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('cancel');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Confirm',
            handler: () => {
                console.log(startTime);
            }
        }]
    });
    alert.present();
    /** prevent default datepicker behavior **/
    return false;
}
```